# Binance Futures Leaderboard - Symbol name not showing up in VPN

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, vpn

I'm doing some webscrapping with Selenium, but when opening the following URL, in the VPN the Symbol name disappears and it only shows "Long".
However, if I open the same URL from a non-VPN it shows correctly.

I honestly don't know what's going on, tried various VPNs Linux and Windows and diff regions.

Any idea?

**EDIT:** I tried it using an AWS EC2 instance of Windows as the VPN

URL https://www.binance.com/en/futures-activity/leaderboard/user?encryptedUid=624EC80EB4E9471226F2021D71598FEB

**How it should look:**

[image]

**How it looks in the VPN: (ignore the different size and so on, it's to show the symbol doesn't appear)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it maybe beacuse that binance detectes selenium,
i would recommend u to use check binance api:https://www.binance.com/pl/binance-api
or you can use requests (with matching headers, tls, headers order etc) and try to scrape it that way

Comment: I don't think that's the case, because when I open it from my own computer through selenium, it gets the data correctly (Symbol is there)

Answer (score 0):

Not that super clear what exactly happening at your end for the Symbol name to disappear.

On my [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) box the following code executes perfecto:

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.binance.com/en/futures-activity/leaderboard/user?encryptedUid=624EC80EB4E9471226F2021D71598FEB')
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.symbol-name"))))
  driver.save_screenshot("FILUSDT.png")
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Screenshot:

[image: FILUSDT]

Comment: Hi sorry I could've been more clear. So in my windows-10 it also executes fine (even on a MAC). The issue seems to be when running my code through a VPN. I'm not sure why it isn't able to identify the symbol name when ran from any VPN.

Comment: I tried your script using an AWS EC2 Windows instance and seems it doesn't locate the symbol. What VPN are you using?